# Using an int as a template parameter that is not known until run-time

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I am trying to use an integer as a template parameter for a class. Here is a sample of the code:

```
template< int array_qty > 
class sample_class {

    public:
        std::array< std::string, array_qty > sample_array;

}
```

If I do so something like this, it works:

```
sample_class< 10 > sample_class_instance;
```

However, let's say that I do not know the value of array_qty (the template parameter) when compiling, and will only know it during run-time. In this case, I would essentially be passing an int variable as the template argument. For the sake of demonstration, the following code does not work:

```
int test_var = 2;
int another_test_var = 5;
int test_array_qty = test_var * another_test_var;

sample_class< test_array_qty > sample_class_instance;
```

I get the following error during compile time when trying the above:

```
the value of ‘test_array_qty’ is not usable in a constant expression
```

I've tried converting test_array_qty to a const while passing it as the template parameter, but that doesn't seem to do the trick either. Is there any way to do this, or am I misusing template parameters? Perhaps they need to be known at compile time?

The goal is NOT to solve this specific approach, but rather to find a way to set the length of the array to an int variable that can be stated when instantiating the class. If there is a way to do this via a template parameter, that would be ideal.

Please note that I have to use an array for this, and NOT a vector which I may end up as a suggestion. Additionally, array_qty will always be a value between 0 and 50 - in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Why do you have to use an array?

Comment: Honestly, `std::vector` is the best option I see here, despite your comment. You can initialize the size with a member initializer.

Comment: For what I am doing, the slight performance difference between an array and a vector is substantial. I don't want to get too much into why I am using an array since that is likely to steer this question off topic.

Comment: What performance difference? Have you a benchmark that proves that there is a difference and it matters?

Comment: if your size is the result of a *computation* that can be performed at compile-time, you might consider using `constexpr`. otherwise, as others said, you can't use `array<>`, and you should switch to `vector<>`

Comment: Delnan, you are doing exactly what I was trying to avoid. Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: I got that. But most of the people who come here denouncing consensus about these things have no idea what they're talking about and no good reason to avoid what they're avoiding. And you did not (neither with your original question, nor with your comments and edits) convince me you are one of the exceptions. Hence I inquire. Plus, if you did show that `std::vector` is measurably slower than `std::array`, I'd learn something.

Comment: My goal isn't to convince you of performance differences between vectors and arrays, nor is it the goal of this question as clearly stated in my post. Please stay on topic.

Comment: I'm not gonna argue further and leave now. But note: [What the question literally asks for is not always what answers should be addressing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But as stated in the question, the objective of the question is to find a way to set the size of the array - not to find an alternate method to store the data. I can tell that you're a smart guy and you are approaching this rationally, but finding an alternate container is not the objective here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done in effect.  But trust me when I say you are asking the wrong question.  So what follows answers your question, even thought doing it is a bad idea almost always.

What you in effect can do is create 50 different programs, one for each of the 50 possible sizes, and then conditionally jump to the one you want.

```
template<int n>
struct prog {
  void run() {
    // ...
  }
};


template<int n>
struct switcher {
  void run(int v) {
    if(v==n)
      prog<n>::run();
    else
      switcher<n-1>::run(v);
  }
};

template<>
struct switcher<-1> {
  void run(int v){
  }
};
```

Call `switcher<50>::run( value );` and if value is 0 to 50, `prog<value>::run()` is invoked.  Within `prog::run` the template parameter is a compile time value.

Horrid hack, and odds are you would be better off using another solution, but it is what you asked for.

Here is a C++14 table-based version:

```
template<size_t N>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<size_t, N>; // C++14

template<size_t M>
struct magic_switch_t {
  template<class F, class...Args>
  using R=std::result_of_t<F(index_t<0>, Args...)>;
  template<class F, class...Args>
  R<F, Args...> operator()(F&& f, size_t i, Args&&...args)const{
    if (i >= M)
      throw i; // make a better way to return an error
    return invoke(std::make_index_sequence<M>{}, std::forward<F>(f), i, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
private:
  template<size_t...Is, class F, class...Args>
  R<F, Args...> invoke(std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&&f, size_t i, Args&&...args)const {
    using pF=decltype(std::addressof(f));
    using call_func = R<F, Args...>(*)(pF pf, Args&&...args);
    static const call_func table[M]={
      [](pF pf, Args&&...args)->R<F, Args...>{
        return std::forward<F>(*pf)(index_t<Is>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      }...
    };
    return table[i](std::addressof(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

`magic_switch_t<N>{}( f, 3, blah1, blah2, etc )` will invoke `f(index_t<3>{}, blah1, blah2, etc)`.

Some C++14 compilers will choke on the variardic pack expansion containing a lambda.  It isn't essential, you can do a workaround, but the workaround is ugly.

The C++14 features are all optional: you can implement it all in C++11, but again, ugly.

The `f` passed basically should be a function object (either a lambda taking `auto` as the first argument, or a manual one).  Passing a function name directly won't work well, because the above best works when the first argument becomes a compile-time value.

You can wrap a function template with a lambda or a function object to help.

Comment: `switcher` can be written to take `prog` as an argument. It can also be rewritten to use an array lookup and function pointer call with a bit of variadic mojo (like traditional switches).  Naturally `switcher` and `prog` `::run` can be given a common return value and pass the result out.

Comment: The table solution can be as inexpensive as a runtime switch.

Comment: Something may have broken that code in the meantime: `R` needs to know about `F`.  Also, `result_of` has been deprecated in C++17, and should now read `invoke_result`.

Answer (score 5):

For C++ 11, non-type template arguments are restricted to the following (§14.3.2/1):

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression (5.19) of the type of the template-parameter; or
> - the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as & id-expression, except that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1.

In C++ 98 and 03, the list is even more restricted. Bottom line: what you're trying to do simply isn't allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Template arguments must be compile-time constants aka "constant expressions" or `constexpr`s for short. So there is no way to do is using templates.

You could use a dynamic-sized array and store its size in an `int`.

Or simply use a `vector`. Be sure to initialize its size in the constructor by passing the desired size to the vector's constructor!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not possible. The template argument must be a constant expression known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but here's my suggestion. I'm guessing the main problem with vectors for you is that they allocate a larger capacity than what you need in order to support dynamic growth. So, can't you write your own simple array class?

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
    private: 
        T* data; 
        unsigned size; 
    public: 
        Array(unsigned size) {
            data = new T[size]; 
            this->size = size; 
        }
        T& operator[](int i) {
            return data[i]; 
        }
        T operator[](int i) const {
            return data[i]; 
        }

        // Depending on your needs, maybe add copy constructor and assignment operator here.
        ...

        unsigned size() {
            return size; 
        }

        ~Array() {
            delete [] data; 
        }
}
```

From what I know, I believe this should be just as fast as the STL array class. In addition, you can create Arrays with sizes unknown until run-time, the Array's memory is handled automatically when it is destroyed, and you don't have to instantiate a new class every time you create a new array with a different size (like you have to do for STL arrays).