# can I get std::array<double, dof> *arr, where dof will be known runtime

Tags: c++, arrays

For some reason, I need any of the following to work:

`std::array<double, dof> *arr;` or `std::array<double, dof> **arr;`

I need `dof` to be obtained from the input file or command line. Or may be, after some calculation, I know the value of `dof`.

Is there a workaround? Or any other container?

(This is to compromise with an existing code and existing library.)

Comment: Please use backticks `\`` to format inline-code. Otherwise, angular brackets `<` and `>` might be mistaken for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417430/using-an-int-as-a-template-parameter-that-is-not-known-until-run-time) answer for more.

Just use an std::vector.

And now, you have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  int dof, value;
  std::cout << "How many elements?\n"; // asume dof is one
  std::cin >> dof;
  std::cout << "Which value?\n"; // asume dof is one
  std::cin >> value;
  std::vector<int> v(dof, value);

  for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
      it != v.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Template arguments must be known at compile time. You can use an `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<double> arr(dof);
```

Also you don't need pointers in any case. If you later need to get a pointer to the underlying array you can use:

```
auto* arr_ptr = arr.data();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need 2d (or 3d) array of fixed size objects. For example, it works in the following way.    sruct{double x; double y} field; field **F; So, I thought, vector<vector<double> > arr(dof); But couldn't get it through arr.data(); The pupose is to generalize the code with minimal change.